# GIT LFS download files selectively after the repo has been cloned skipping lfs

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have git repo that uses LFS (artifactory) to store larger files. My use case is to clone the repo skipping LFS (GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1) and then perform some operation on the repo that gives out a list of files to download. The current strategy to download files is to directly request it from artifactory (using artifactory api) which works fine but involves a lot of overhead like handling, parsing request/response and writing it to a file. Also in future if there is another lfs repo that uses a different store, then it will not work with artifactory api.

I want to find a way if this can be done with git-lfs commands that's independent of the lfs store (artifactory in this case). Something like `git-lfs fetch file1 file2 .. **files`. Please advise how can I achieve this. Thank you!